# Does Judges 5:14 imply that Ephraim had distant Amalekite roots?

Tags: translation-philosophy, hermeneutical-approaches, historical-interpretation, judges

Judges 5:14

> **Some came from Ephraim, whose roots were in Amalek**; ; Benjamin was
> with the people who followed you. From Makir captains came down, from
> Zebulun those who bear a commander's staff. (NIV)
>
> **מִנִּ֣י אֶפְרַ֗יִם שָׁרְשָׁם֙ בַּעֲמָלֵ֔ק** אַחֲרֶ֥יךָ בִנְיָמִ֖ין
> בַּֽעֲמָמֶ֑יךָ מִנִּ֣י מָכִ֗יר יָֽרְדוּ֙ מְחֹ֣קְקִ֔ים וּמִ֨זְּבוּלֻ֔ן
> מֹשְׁכִ֖ים בְּשֵׁ֥בֶט סֹפֵֽר

How should understand this cryptic poem? Is the translation by the NIV correct? If so, what does it mean that Ephraim's roots are in Amalek? Is it possible that in the distant past the Ephraimite people mingled with the Amalekites and intermarried with them? Is it possible that the text is hinting at that?

Answer (score 4):

Without disputing any of other answers, I wanted to provide more interpretations and arguments:

### Emendation switching "Amalek" with "valley"

*Several manuscripts of the LXX have “in the valley” rather than “into Amalek.”*
Brannan, R., & Loken, I. (2014). The Lexham Textual Notes on the Bible (Jdg 5:14). Bellingham, WA: Lexham Press.

### Interpeting "Amalek" as a geographic marker in which some Ephramaites lived

New American Commentary:
From the New American Commentary:

> The following phrase, “whose roots were in Amaleq,” makes little sense
> in the context unless at this time the Amalekites (who later joined
> with the Midianites in oppressing Israel; cf. 6:3) had established a
> foothold in some of the Ephraimite highlands.

Block, D. I. (1999). Judges, Ruth (Vol. 6, p. 232). Nashville: Broadman & Holman Publishers.

Keil & Delitzsch's commentary:

> “From (מִנִּי, poetical for מִן) Ephraim,” sc., there came fighting
> men; not the whole tribe, but only nobles or brave men, and indeed
> those whose roots were in Amalek, i.e., those who were rooted or had
> taken root, i.e., had settled and spread themselves out upon the
> tribe-territory of Ephraim, which had formerly been inhabited by
> Amalekites, the mount of the Amalekites, mentioned in Judg. 12:15 (for
> the figure itself, see Isa. 27:6, Ps. 80:10, and Job 5:3). “Behind
> thee,” i.e., behind Ephraim, there followed Benjamin among thy
> (Ephraim’s) people (עֲמָמִים, a poetical form for עַמִּים, in the
> sense of hosts).

Keil, C. F., & Delitzsch, F. (1996). Commentary on the Old Testament (Vol. 2, p. 230). Peabody, MA: Hendrickson.

Bible Knowledge Commentary:

> The explanation about Ephraim’s roots being in Amalek (v. 14)
> apparently indicates that the Ephraimites lived in the central hill
> country previously occupied by the Amalekites.

Lindsey, F. D. (1985). Judges. In J. F. Walvoord & R. B. Zuck (Eds.), The Bible Knowledge Commentary: An Exposition of the Scriptures (Vol. 1, p. 390). Wheaton, IL: Victor Books.

### interpreting "root" as "rooted out" or defeated

LXX : *Ephraim rooted out those in Amalek,*

The Lexham English Septuagint. (2020). (Second Edition, Jdg 5:14). Bellingham, WA: Lexham Press.

And JPS Commentary:

> One solution that continued into the Middle Ages was to
> interpret the passage as referring to heroes who stemmed from Ephraim
> and fought against Amalek (e.g., Joshua and Saul; see Exod. 17:8–13
> and 1 Samuel 15, respectively). Compare Targum Jonathan, Rashi, and
> Kimḥi.
>
> Fishbane, M. A. (2002). Haftarot (p. 104). Philadelphia: The Jewish
> Publication Society.

Also, Rashi:

> In Ephraim. From Ephraim emerged the root of Joshua bin Nun's
> dominance over Amaleik ( Joshua was descended from Ephraim, son of
> Yoseif, and Amaleik was a descendant of Eisov. Scripture states, “The
> house of Yaakov shall be fire, the house of Yoseif flame, the house of
> Eisov chaff” [Ovadiah, 18], teaching that the descendants of Yoseif
> shall devour the descendants of Eisov as flame consumes chaff.
> (Yalkut, 51. Cf. Rashi to [[Genesis, 30:25]])) when he debilitated
> them with the sword.24([[Exodus, 17:13]].) This passage is related to
> the preceding one, as it explains ""Adonoy empowered me over the
> mighty"" by establishing Joshua's dominance over Amaleik.

Rashi Commentaries. (n.d.). (p. 860).

One problem with this interpretation is that root is in construct form attached to Amalek, so viewing it as "rooted out" rather than "root of" would require some textual emendation.

### That this is a prophetic passage that describes some of Ephraim who *will behave* like Amalekites later in Judges

Here is the NICOT commentary:

> What we get is a rather cryptic statement about the Ephraimites which
> is at best ambivalent and at worst entirely (and sarcastically)
> negative. The meaning depends largely on how we take the opening
> phrase, minnî ʾep̱rayim. If the minnî is partitive, it could mean
> “some [a few] Ephraimites.” If it is originative, what we would then
> have is a blanket statement: “Those who are from/of Ephraim” (i.e.,
> the Ephraimites in general). Since, however, verses 14 and 15 in
> general deal with tribes that did participate, it seems best to take
> this opening statement as positive: “Some [went down] from Ephraim.”
> What follows, though, can hardly be anything other than negative:
> literally, “their root [was] in Amalek.” Overall the force of the line
> seems to be that while volunteers did come from Ephraim, they
> displayed some “Amalekite” characteristics; that is, they were
> hostile, quarrelsome. At this stage in the book such a mixed report on
> the Ephraimites is very puzzling, but the negative aspect of it will
> be confirmed by the way the Ephraimites behave in both the Gideon and
> Jephthah episodes, which follow (8:1–3; 12:1).

Webb, B. G. (2012). The Book of Judges. (R. K. Harrison & R. L. Hubbard Jr., Eds.) (p. 211). Grand Rapids, MI; Cambridge, UK: William B. Eerdmans Publishing Company.

Comment: "Several manuscripts of the LXX have “in the valley” rather than “into Amalek." For that +1. I was completely unaware of this emendation. Indeed, it makes totally sense. Valley in Hebrew is עמק if we add only one letter "lamed" it becomes עמלק (Amalek), so it makes sense that it originally said עמק and somehow evolved into עמלק (Amalek) making this poem look more enigmatic than it actually is!

Comment: The valley may actually refer to the famous "valley of Jezreel" which was part of Ephraim's territory. The Ephraimites may have originally settled there and from there spread to the "hills of Ephraim". I'm not a scholar, just speculating.

Comment: @Bach Thanks! My geographic knowledge is poor, but I think Valley of Jezreel is to the north of the inheritance of Ephraim, on the border of Manasseh just south of Galilee and heading up to present Haifa. Really I need a better atlas that has this all layed out instead squinting at different maps.

Comment: You're probably right, but Ephraim's boundaries in the times of judges might not have been so well defined. It may also be that Manasseh and Ephraim were lumped together as one tribe. But you're right that most maps have them in the territory of Issachar or Manasseh. In any case, if it can be proven that they originally came from Jezreel then it won't matter whether Jezreel itself was part of Ephraim, Issachar or Manasseh later on.

Comment: Interestingly, according to Jewish virtual library "While there are other valleys in Israel, in Hebrew the Jezreel Valley is often referred to simply as “Ha’emek - The Valley”. Not sure if this reflects only modern Hebrew or ancient Hebrew as well. It's cool nevertheless.

Comment: It should also be noted that Manasseh itself is never mentioned in the song of Deborah, although Machir his son is.

Answer (score 0):

the book of judges does not seem to know other parts of the bible placing amalek in the negev and part of the edomites. judges holds no grudges against these peoples and even considers them family and places them in the north

Comment: Yerachmiel, I appreciate your feedback, however on BH evidence must be provided to support assertions, unsupported assertions are at risk of being closed or taken off. Please edit your answer to reflect this. Even citing verses within Judges can be used as evidence.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that Joseph's wife, Asenath, came from Amalek heritage? The passages in Genesis do not reveal her ethnicity

Comment: Interesting suggestion. In Gen. 36 in the Edomite family tree we find a name basemath (one of Esau's wives, essentially Amalek's step-granny), which is perhaps phonetically similar to Asenath? But it's unlikely, given the fact that she is described as daughter of Potiphera which sounds very much like an Egyptian name.  The name Asenath itself could be dervied from the Egyptian goddess Neith. Alternatively it may be related to Anath a semitic goddess (which fits Edom). However some Rabbinic traditions suggest that she was not of Egyptian descent. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asenath

Comment: Mysterite please also make sure to take the tour of our site, and see how this site is different.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The tribes were commanded by God to destroy ALL of the ‘giants’ including women & children; but I believe that Ephraim was the one tribe that compromised God’s command by not destroying ALL of them and allowed some to live and work in their land, instead? Essentially making peace with the enemy if the enemy served them. Trying to remember where I read that? Perhaps in Jasher?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).